# Asignación de array con funciones

Tags: javascript, html

Mi problema es el siguiente. He creado una función que devuelve un numero entre 0 y 3:

```
function crnd() {
    return (Math.random() * 4) | 0;
}
```

y he intentado crear un array en 2d con esta función dentro, con la esperanza de que me quede un array con números aleatorios dentro.

el array en cuestión:

```
const boardMat = [
    [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5]
    [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5]
    [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5]
    [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5]
    [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5]
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
];
```

mi objetivo es que quede de la siguiente forma, por ejemplo:

```
const boardMat = [
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 5]
    [...etc...]
];
```

No veo conveniente usar `.push()` ya que el numero 5 es fijo.
He probado subiendo la función sobre el array, y también probé cambiar de `const` a `let`.

¿por qué esto no funciona? ¿cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: No te funciona porque no separas los sub-grupos por coma. Prueba así: `var boardMat = [
[crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
[crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
[crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
[crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
[crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ¿Por qué no funciona?

Tu código no funciona porque no estás separando los sub-arrays con una coma.

Aquí funciona:

```js
function crnd() {
  return (Math.random() * 4) | 0;
}
var boardMat = [
  [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
  [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
  [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
  [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
  [crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), crnd(), 5],
  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
];
console.info("Hard coded");
console.log(boardMat);
```

---

#### Una forma dinámica

Con este código puedes crear los elementos de forma dinámica, según los valores de las variables:

- `a` : cantidad de números aleatorios que hay que agregar
- `f` : valor fijo
- `c` : número de columnas del array bidimensional

Se crean primero los sub-arrays, poniendo en cada uno al final el valor fijo (`5`). Luego se agrega un sub-array lleno con todos elementos del valor fijo.

Quizá algún gurú de Javascript encuentre todavía una forma más simple de hacerlo. De esta manera puedes automatizar el código, en caso de necesitar otro valor fijo distinto de `5` o de necesitar arrays con otras dimensiones.

Espero te sirva.

```js
    /*
      a : aleatorios a agregar
      f : valor fijo para el final
      c : columnas del array
    */
    var a = 5;
    var f = 5;
    var c = 6;

    function fillRandom(a, f) {
      var tmp = 
       Array.from({length: a}, (v, k) => (Math.random() * 4) | 0);
      tmp.push(f);
      return tmp;
    }
    var mArray = (c, a, f) => [...Array(c)].map(e => fillRandom(a, f));
    var arrFinal = mArray(c, a, f);
    /* 
      Sub-array con el valor fijo (5)
    */
    var fixArray = new Array(c).fill(f);

    /*
      Lo agregamos al array dinámico
    */
    arrFinal.push(fixArray);

    /* Prueba */
    console.info("Dynamic");
    console.log(arrFinal);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! No puedo creer que no haya visto tal error. Gracias de nuevo por proporcionar el codigo!